# News on SG values of Grundy's Game?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Is there any recent research into the [Sprague-Grundy values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem) of [Grundy's game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundy%27s_game)?

It was calculated to $2^{35}$ integers but with no sight of recurrence.

Has anyone come up with anything new to compute a SG formula for the game?